# Can LiCb batteries overheat if not given any airflow?

Tags: batteries

Is there any reasonable risk of having 3v LiCb button batteries overheat if enclosed in plastic and used?

Comment: No, because the power draw is so low that the heat generated is low so heat has enough time to get away rather than accumulate.

Comment: @DKNguyen can you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the power draw is so low that the heat generated is low that it has enough to time to disperse and dissipate rather than accumulate and increase temperature.